# Remove list from drop down menu after selected previously

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

In my page, there are 3 drop down menu.

Dropdown 1 : for storing car model which retrieved from CarTab in database (SQL)

Dropdown 2 : for storing username

Dropdown 3 : for storing plate num

The function of the all drop down menu, there are related to each other. Let says if Admin select Honda Vios in drop down 1, the drop down 2 will display usernames who only booked Honda Vios previously. Then in drop down 3, it will display the plate number of the car. For example, in the CarTab, there are 6 Honda vios and of course the cars have different plate number. Right? So, the drop down 3, will show to the Admin the plate number of the selected car.

Admin select Honda Vios in drop down 1, next drop down 2 will show list of users who selected Honda vios and the Admin select User A, and the plate number is SGH 12BC. Then Admin hit the save button and save it into new table in database.

```
<td>Car Model</td>
<td class="style21">
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="42px" Width="146px" 
AutoPostBack="True">
<asp:ListItem>Please Choose</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Honda Vios</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Honda Civic</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Honda City</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Honda Jazz</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="style18">
User</td>
<td class="style19">
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Username" 
DataValueField="Username" Height="36px" Width="137px" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Connection %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [Username] FROM [Rsvp] WHERE ([Model] = @Model)">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList2" Name="Model" 
PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="style16">
Plate
</td>
<td class="style17">
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" 
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Plate" DataValueField="Plate" 
Height="45px" Width="141px" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Connection %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [Plate] FROM [CarTab] WHERE ([Model] = @Model)">
</asp:SqlDataSource
```

**Here is the question:**
how to remove the username and the plate number selected by Admin? Meaning, when Admin login, the username for Honda vios list and plate number  will not appear again. I need help. Please guide me.

Comment: Excuse if I dont fully understand, but are you asking how to clear the drop down list?

Comment: I am asking the value (username and plate number) no longer available after being selected previously

Comment: Do you mean these values are no longer available for current session or they should be permanently disabled?

Comment: Well, then you will have to keep track of what all Users for a given Model have been processed and again what all NumberPlates for a given User have been processed, this can be done by setting additional flags in database tables.

Comment: Can you tell me how to flag in table?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a lookup table on the database that tracks which items have need selected. Then add a join to that table.
Something like this:

```
SELECT [Username] FROM [Rsvp] join SelectedItems
on [Rsvp].ID =  SelectedItems.ID
WHERE [Model] = @Model and SelectedItems.HasBeenSelected = False
```

Comment: First you would need to the table to the database. Then when the user click the save button you would do an insert into the new lookup table. But the query above would be your new SelectCommand

Comment: Yes, you will need to add the join to the lookup table. Do you understand joins ?

Comment: Not really. But its ok. I'll try to do it first. :)

Comment: @ColorShadow this link will help you with understanding joins http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: hey, it give me error. It says that invalid object name = selecteditems

Comment: Did you create the table with the with the columns names? My code is just an example. You need to create a table for selectedItems

Comment: its ok then. Thnks for your time :)